# Group G with elements of specific order

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, dihedral-groups

What is an example of a group G with elements a and b such that the order or a and b is 2, but the order of ab is 3? I'm thinking some sort of Dihedral group perhaps?

Comment: $S_3$ with two transpositions.

Comment: In line with your intuition any dihedral group with a rotation of order $3$ works as every rotation is the product of two reflections.

Comment: You have asked two questions within an hour, both asking for an example, and both being answerable with the same example, which also happens to be the smallest possible example and the first one that should always come to mind when trying to find examples. It would be better if you spent just a bit more time working on the problems yourself before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

In the symmetric group $S_3$, $(12)(23) = (132)$

Comment: Sorry but where did you get 12 and 23 from? Would the dihedral group D2n with n=3 also satisfy this group?

Comment: $D_6$ is the same group as $S_3$

Comment: That is the (standard) permutation notation for elements in symmetric groups